# Dense subset of functions with derivative nowhere differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis

I have met a problem which may requires additional knowledge which I do not know.

Given a complete metric space $(C^1 [a,b], ||\cdot||_{C^1})$. Prove that $\exists X \subset (C^1 [a,b], ||\cdot||_{C^1})$, $X$ dense, such that for each function $ f \in X$, $f'$ is nowhere differentiable.

Someone told me that this problem is based on a theorem which might like the following statement:

$\exists X \subset (C^0 [a,b], ||\cdot||_{\infty})$, $X$ dense, such that for each function $ f \in X$, $f$ is nowhere differentiable.

So, my question is, how to prove this problem based on the given theorem, and where I can find a proof to the original theorem? I think the theorem is very important and famous but I do not know the name of the theorem and I can't find the proof of it on the internet.(The most related topic, I guess, is Weierstrass Function.) By the way, I think the problem might be extended to $(C^n [a,b], ||\cdot||_{C^n})$. Are there any even more generalized theorem about this series about metric spaces? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you consider all the primitive of all elements in $X$ it should work ?

Comment: The proof of the theorem uses the Baire category: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in my comment I think you should just integrate, you exactly have the regularity you are waiting for and it should be easy to deduc the density (essentially because if two derivatives are close to each other then up to some well chosen constant the functions themselves are very close, the whole thing works, of cours because you are on a compact set).

To answer you second question the "given theorem" you mention is an application (not so hard but not easy, in my opinion) of the Baire's theorem. You can actually show that your set $X$ contains a $G_{\delta}$ (countable intersection of open dense subsets) which is (using Baire's theorem) dense itself.

Comment: Oh! You mean that because f is continuous, I can get by answer simply be integration?

Comment: Because $f$ is continuous its primitive will be $C^1$, because its derivative is $f$. For the Baire thing, if you wikipediate this you will find it as a classical application of the Baire's theorem.